# php preg_match function escaping apostrophize

Tags: php, php-7.2

In php, I'm validating a string in such a way that it is:

- At least on character long
- Contains only alpha numerical digits plus the symbols dash, underline and dollar sign (- _ $)

So my resulting code is:

```
if(!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\$]+/", $input))
     abort(400);
// else continues
```

It is working nice except for the apostrophize characters ' and " in such a way that if the string contains one of these two caracters, it was supposed to fail the verification but that is not what is happening. I think my regex patterns is not well structured, but I can't find the problem here.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9-_$]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only check if the chars exists anywhere in the string (in this case `Hello`). You need to regex with beginn (`^`) and end (`$`) of string:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_$]+$/", 'Hello"')) {
   abort(400);
} else {
    //continues
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/3mZD3L

---

**Should I escape or not the `$` inside the square brackets?**

In this case you don't need to escape the `$` with `\`. You can escape always the regular expression chars if you need them as chars and not regex char: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Comment: btw, should I escape or not the `$` inside the square brackets?

Comment: you don't need to escape `$`. with or without escape makes no difference (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\$]+$/", $input);
```